# RIA Webservices Include not working after deployment

Tags: sql-server, wcf, ria

I have a RIA Webservices call that works fine on my dev machine.

```
 var results = repositoryFactory.For<RE059>().AsQueryable()
    .Where(
        r =>
        r.Bk_Term == TerminalName &&
        (r.Ld_Unld_Act == "DH" || r.Ld_Unld_Act == "DS" || r.Ld_Unld_Act == "DR")
        && r.Bk_Term != "Domestic")
        .Include("RE059Note");
return results;
```

If I remove the .Include the deployed version works fine. When I add it SQL Profiler doesn't show any database call, obviously no data shows up and my trace log shows an exception but there is no Message or Native Error Code. Only an Exception Type of System.ServiceModel.FaultException.

SQL profiler shows the same SQL user is used for the production and dev version. I checked SQL rights and the SQL that Profiler shows for the dev version runs fine in SQL Mgmt Studio with the respective SQL user.

What kind of things might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to install the Microsoft Code First Preview. It has .Include as an extension method.

[ADO.Net Entity Framework Code First Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ADB688-F8A7-4D28-86B1-B6235385389D)